# How to find if there is a string that is in both files?

Tags: php

I have a list of keywords in my strings.lst file,and I want to echo all the filenames in a directory and it's subdirectories, that contain at least one of the strings from the file.

Here is what I've written so far, but how to compare the two files?

```
function lookForString($filename)
{

{

function listFolderFiles($dir)
{
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    foreach($ffs as $ff)
    {
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..’)
        {
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff))
                listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
                else
                lookForString($ff);
        }
    }
}
```

I have know idea how to write the lookForString function, can anyone help me?

In other words, how to convert this

```
$handle = fopen($filename, 'r');
while (($buffer = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    if (strpos($buffer, $myString) !== false) {
        echo $filename;
        break; 
    }      
}
fclose($handle);
```

into a searching for multiple strings?

Comment: Do you have to do that using PHP? This would take a very few bash commands.

Comment: yeah, i need php for the project :\